# meteor accounts index

Tags: indexing, meteor, accounts

I would like to know if the username, email addresses and profile name of the Meteor.users collection  are indexed if not is there a way to index them ?

does it cost much to run regex on this field without them being indexed ?

Comment: a general way to list indexes on a collections is using mongo's [getIndexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/#db.collection.getIndexes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the indexes Meteor currently ensures on the `users` collection -- from [accounts_server.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js)

```
/// DEFAULT INDEXES ON USERS
Meteor.users._ensureIndex('username', {unique: 1, sparse: 1});
Meteor.users._ensureIndex('emails.address', {unique: 1, sparse: 1});
Meteor.users._ensureIndex('services.resume.loginTokens.token',
                        {unique: 1, sparse: 1});
```

Comment: thanks, i guess i'll have to add my own in the server side for custom profile fields